# use pipe to set the elements of a data.frame elegantly

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Does anyone know how to use `%>%` or `%<>%`to do this:

```
cars[cars$speed < 10 & cars$dist < 95 | cars$speed > 100,] <- NA
```

I tried:

```
cars %>% 
  .[.$speed < 10 &.$dist < 95 | .$dist > 100,] %>% 
  set(., j=1:dim(.)[2], value = NA)
```

but it's not the right way.

Comment: dplyr can't assign to a subset very elegantly; in one way or another, you have to reassign entire columns. Often this happens with `ifelse`, here `cars %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(speed < 10 & dist < 95 | speed > 100, NA, .x))`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to calculate the row indices which we want to change and then use it to `replace` values in all columns using `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)

cars %>%
   mutate(inds = (speed < 10 & dist < 95) | speed > 100) %>%
   mutate_all(funs(replace(.,inds, NA))) %>%
   select(-inds)


#   speed dist
#1     NA   NA
#2     NA   NA
#3     NA   NA
#4     NA   NA
#5     NA   NA
#6     NA   NA
#7     10   18
#8     10   26
#9     10   34
#10    11   17
#...
```